# Angular form shows old value while saving

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, angular-reactive-forms, ngrx-store

I have a form component that has this issue of showing previous values during a save. If I close the form and open it up again, then the new values are correctly shown. So, I think what is happening is that `selectedContact` is still the old values, which gets past into the form as `contactForm` during the save and overwrites the new values with the old values on the form controls during the save. I'm using NgRx Store to manage my data.

I'm not sure how to stop the form from showing the old values during save. Is there a way to pause the form from updating?

Parent modal component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'parent-modal',
  template: `
    <ng-template #childTemplate>
      <contact-form
        [contactForm]="contactForm"
        [loading]="(loading$ | async)!"
        (cancel)="close()"
        (save)="save($event)"
        *ngIf="contactForm"
      ></contact-form>

    <web-modal
      [childTemplate]="childTemplate"
      [visible]="(isPopupOpen$ | async)!"
      (cancel)="close()"
    >
    </web-modal>
  `,
  styles: [],
})
export class ContactModalComponent {
  @Input() public selectedContact!: Contact | null;
  public isPopupOpen$!: Observable<boolean>;
  public loading$: Observable<boolean>;

  public constructor(
    private store: Store<ContactPartialState>,
    configurationStore: Store<ConfigurationState>,
  ) {
    this.isPopupOpen$ = store.select(contacttQuery.getIsContactOpen);
    this.loading$ = store.select(contactQuery.getLoading);
  }

  public get contactForm(): Contact {
    return this.selectedContact as Contact;
  }

  public close(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(closeContact());
  }

  public save(form: Contact): void {
    this.store.dispatch(saveContact({ payload: form }));
  }
}
```

Child form component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'contact-form',
  templateUrl: '../contact-form/contact-form.component.html',
})
export class ContactFormComponent implements OnChanges {
  @Input() public contactForm!: Contact | null;
  @Input() public loading: boolean;
  @Output() public cancel: EventEmitter<void>;
  @Output() public save: EventEmitter<Contact>;

  public form!: FormGroup;

  public constructor(
    fb: FormBuilder,
  ) {
    this.loading = false;
    this.cancel = new EventEmitter<void>();
    this.save = new EventEmitter<Contact>();
    this.contactForm = new Contact();
    this.createForm();
  }

  public ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.createForm();
  }

  public createForm(): void {
    // add form controls
  }

  public emitCancel(): void {
    this.cancel.emit();
  }

  public emitSave(): void {
    this.form.markAllAsTouched();
    if (this.form.valid) {
      const contact = new Contact(this.form.value);
      this.save.emit(contact);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't update your `selectedContact` in your `ContactModalComponent`.

```js
export class ContactModalComponent {
  public save(form: Contact): void {
    this.selectedContact = form;
    this.store.dispatch(saveContact({ payload: form }));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this resolved the issue for me. It was so simple, yet I couldn't see it!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways around this issue.

1. Set your form to only create once in ngOnChange

   ```
   public ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges): void {
       if(changes.contactForm.isFirstChange()){
           this.createForm();
     }  
   }
   ```
2. If there is a specific UUID in your form, that UUID can also be triggger to update form in ngOnChangeHook

   ```
   ngOnInit(){
       this.activeId$.pipe(
           takeWhile(()=>this.componentAlive),
           distinctUntilChanged()
       ).subscribe(){
         this.createForm()
       }
   }
   public ngOnChanges(changes:SimpleChanges): void {
       if(changes.contactForm.id){
           activeId$.next(this.contactForm.id)
       }  
   }

   ngOnDestroy(){
      this.componentAlive = false;
   }

   activeId$ = new BehaviorSubject(null);
   componentAlive = true;
   ```
3. Simply create form via a different liftCycleHook

   ```
   ngOnInit(){
     this.createForm()
   }
   ```